# Split a Line Based on Whitespace Using python

Tags: python-3.4

I am a beginner in python. Below there is a text file. If we see (pitiara, Ram1) there is nothing. I want to add 0 over there and all the place where it is blank. And i want to make all the numbers a three digit number by adding 0's. Can anyone tell me how to write a script for that. It would be a great help to me.

```
Name       Rom1        Ram1        Ram2       Rom2       Rom3

Prakash    156          79          26                    89

Amu         57         380         129        666        

Pitiara    289                      96                    89

Nagna       72          79         326         52         96
```

Comment: How do you know that it is Ram1 that is empty and not Ram2? Also, in case it is absent, do you want to put 000 or 0 ?

Comment: Now you can see.

Comment: This is a text file right? How can you get that arrangement? Is there an extra whitespace or a tab to indicate it is absent?

Comment: i want to make all the numbers a three digit number.

Comment: You did not answer my query yet. Being a text file, how are you ensuring that a particular column is absent. Is there an extra whitespace or a tab or a comma?

Comment: The text file is in the way what shown above.

Comment: There is only whitespace to show it's absent

Comment: Does that mean there are lot of white-space. Is it a TAB? Is there any way you can upload a snippet of actual text file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an empty value is just one whitespace, the below script should work.

```
lines=[line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('test.txt')]
b=[];
c=[];
for l in lines:
    t=l.split(" ")
    print(t)
    c=[];
    for a in t:
        if (a.isdigit()):
            a=a.zfill(3)         
        elif (a=='' or a==' '):
            a='000';
        c.append(a)
    b.append(c)
```

You can then write the list b back to a text file. I recommend saving it as CSV for future purposes and also recommend against using the three digit as it wont serve any purpose.

lines has the entire content of the text. Rstrips the EOL character. Each line is stored as list. l is the individual line in the lines list. a is each individual "word" seperated by a single whitespace. zfill fills any string with 0 as a prefix to match the length.